# Print 1..N² in NxN matrix, starting at bottom-right and zig-zag

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, logic

Given an input *n*, I want to print *n* lines with each *n* numbers such that the numbers 1 through *n²* are displayed in a zig-zag way, starting with 1 appearing at the bottom-right corner of the output matrix, and 2 at the end of the one-but-last row, ...etc.

### Examples:

Given Input 3.

Print:

```
9 4 3
8 5 2
7 6 1
```

Given Input 1.

Print:

```
1
```

Given Input 4.

Print:

```
 13 12 5 4
 14 11 6 3
 15 10 7 2
 16 9 8 1
```

### Attempt

```py
n = int(input("Enter dimensions of matrix :"))
m = n
x = 1
columns = []
for row in range(n):
    inner_column = []
    for col in range(m):
        inner_column.append(x)
        x = x + 1
    columns.append(inner_column)
for inner_column in columns:
    print(' '.join(map(str, inner_column)))
```

I've tried something like this, but it prints out the array incorrectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code explicitly performs `x = 1` and then `x = x + 1` in a loop. As you need the first column in reverse order, and there are `n*n` numbers to output, instead the first top-left value should be `x = n * n` and in the first column it should decrease like with `x = x - 1`. The next column should be filled from end to start, and the next should be filled from start to end, ...etc.

I would suggest making an iterator that visits *rows* in that zig-zag manner: 0, 1, 2, ... n - 1, and then n - 1, n - 2, ... 0, and back from the start. With that iterator you know exactly to which row you should append the next `x` value:

```py
# Helper function to generate row numbers in zig-zag order, for as
#   long as needed.
def zigzag(n):
    if n % 2:
        yield from range(n)
    while True:
        yield from range(n - 1, -1, -1)
        yield from range(n)

n = int(input("Enter dimensions of matrix :"))
matrix = [[] for _ in range(n)]
visit = zigzag(n)
for x in range(n*n, 0, -1):
    matrix[next(visit)].append(x)
```

Then print it:

```py
for row in matrix:
    print(' '.join(map(str, row)))
```

Comment: Not the correct output, close though.

Comment: What is the logic of the output you need?

Comment: Any feedback to the update?

Comment: VERY close. For a matrix of dimension 4 this is incorrect. for dimension 5 it is correct. Something needs tweaking I am not too sure.

Comment: So what do you expect for even dimensions? Like I asked above, what is the logic of the output you need? The question doesn't give any information about it... just an example output for input 3. Let me guess: the 1 should always be output at the end of the last row? I have added 2 lines of code in the function to make it behave that way...

Comment: Cool! I am a little confused with the helper function and how it works, but it gives correct output. Thanks